# Add to Google Sheets with a Google Apps Script Web App

Tags: html, web-applications, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just getting started with Google Apps Script and I want to be able to add to a Google Sheet through a web app, but I'm having issues. This is what I have so far:

```
function addRow(input) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://spreadsheeturl');
  sheet.appendRow([input]);
} 

function doGet(e) {
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  addRow(params);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(params);
}
```

When I type in the URL they give me with the parameters I want to add to the spreadsheet it doesn't add anything to the spreadsheet, but if I don't pass any parameters it adds it to the spreadsheet.

For example, https://script.google.com/.../exec adds *{"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"","parameters":{}}* to the spreadsheet, but https://script.google.com/.../exec?user=jsmith doesn't add anything to the spreadsheet.

Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) I can see something about URL parameters and event objects, but they give no further information. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Tomi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your script works. In your script,

- When `https://script.google.com/.../exec` is requested, `{"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"","parameters":{}}` is added to the last row at the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.
- When `https://script.google.com/.../exec?user=jsmith` is requested, `{"parameter":{"user":"jsmith"},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"user=jsmith","parameters":{"user":["jsmith"]}}` is added to the last row at the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.

So can you confirm the following points on your script editor again?

1. At Publish -> Deploy as web app, redeploy as a new version for `Project version:`.

   - When the scripts for Web Apps was modified, the modified script is required to be redeployed as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps.
2. At Publish -> Deploy as web app, it confirms whether `Execute the app as:` and `Who has access to the app:` are "me" and "Anyone, even anonymous", respectively.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.